# Gnuplot: how to remove the lines in the legends of a error bar plot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, legend

Gnuplot 4.6.5

I want to remove the line in the legend of a yerrorbars plot.

Here is the test code:

```
set term wxt;
set key bottom;
plot '-' title 'data 1' with yerrorbars pt 7;
#a1 Avg-r Std-r
0.0 0.005554 0.0008
0.1 0.01527 0.0097
0.2 0.363396 0.1345
0.3 0.754732 0.0584
0.4 0.887269 0.0136
0.5 0.944382 0.0089
0.6 0.971147 0.0058
0.7 0.984564 0.0040
0.8 0.99171 0.00296
0.9 0.995385 0.0021
1.0 0.997495 0.00165
e
```

It gives:

[image]

I want:

[image]

Help will be much appreciated!

I still want the bars in the main figure, but want to get rid of them in the legends.

Comment: This is a workaround, maybe some one has a proper solution: doing `set key samplen -1` will make the lines in the legend so short that they will be hidden on top (or behind) the dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround, in addition to the one given in the comments, is to plot twice, first with a smaller dot size and with the error bars and *no title*, and then on top of it with the desired dot size and no error bars:

```
plot "data" u 1:2:3 with yerrorbars pt 7 lc 1 ps 0.5 not, \
"data" u 1:2 pt 7 lc 1 ps 1 title "data1"
```

[image]